# How to override taxvat.phtml

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml, plugin, after-plugin

Hi dears I want to override taxvat.phtml in `vendor > magento > module-customer > view > frontend > templates > widget`

Before I try to create a file **Vendor > Module > etc > di.xml** with this code :

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name">
    <plugin name="vatcode" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat"/>
</type>
```

and in Taxvat code :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat as Taxobj;

class Taxvat
{

    public function after_construct(Taxobj $result)
    {
        $result->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::widget/taxvat.phtml');
        return $result;
    }

}
```

after run but i have below error :

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat::after_construct() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat, instance of Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name\Interceptor given, called in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Before Plugin type for set your custom template.

```
public function beforeSetTemplate(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat $subject, $template): array
    {
        $template = 'Vendor_Module::widget/taxvat.phtml';
        return [$template];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Madani I tried. shown below error :

`Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat::beforeSetTemplate() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat, instance of Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name\Interceptor given, called in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 121`

Comment: Did you ran the magento commands ? And also make sure you defined the proper type name in di.xml for plugin.

Comment: Yes i ran this command : 
`rm -rf pub/static/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && bin/magento se:up && bin/magento se:stat:de -f && bin/magento c:f` 
and i have find problem now

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to like this :

```
class Taxvat
{
    public function after_construct(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name $subject, $result)
    {
        $result->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::widget/taxvat.phtml');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi dhiren I tried. shown below error :
`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name\Interceptor::isRequired`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the taxvat.phtml file in your theme.
app/design/frontend/theme_vendor/theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/taxtvat.phtml

Comment: Thank you dear wang. I need Add it in module